# Extend a language with additional keywords?

Tags: listings, languages, keywords

I'm using `listings` and I want to extend a language with additional keywords for highlightning. I know there is an option `morekeywords` available, but that only works for a particular `lstset` declaration and I don't want to have to copy-paste all keywords into all listings. I've tried declaring the keywords as part of a command but that doesn't work (probably because the command is not expanded and I don't know how to fix that).

So is there any way of declaring a new language by copying an existing one and just adding more keywords?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can define the keywords in a separate file and just include it in your preamble.  Here is an example of adding `for` and `downto` as new keywords:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,%
    }%

% Add your keywords here, and have this in a separate file
% and include it in your preamble
\lstset{emph={%  
    downto, for%
    },emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries\underbar}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
y = 0
for i = n downto 0
    y = a_i + x * y
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I never thought about using a separate `\lstset` to define the keywords! This solved my problem!

Comment: How do I use this to define multiple types of formatting (i.e. make "foo" red and "bar" green)?  If I put subsequent `\lstset{emph=...` commands only the last one seems to take effect and all previous ones are ignored.

Comment: @PGmath: I think the way to do that would be to define styles (similar too the other answers) and invoke the desired style.  If that does not answer your question, I would suggest you ask a new question and be sure to include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: In my opinion the answers with \lstdefinestyle are way more suitable and elegant to answer the question.

Answer (score 66):

It seems that `morekeywords` also works for extending a language. For instance the Python keyword `super` isn't in the list of default keywords. In my preamble, I can set it as a keyword by doing:

```
\lstset{language=Python}
\lstset{
 morekeywords={super}
}
```

Of course, it would be ideal to contribute those missing keywords to the listings package.

Comment: Does this only add the keyword to the current language?

Answer (score 16):

As Dominique said,

```
\lstset{language=Python}
\lstset{
morekeywords={super}
}
```

works, but doing so firstly add the Python language to all listing and then adds the keyword to all languages.

To add the keyword only for one language use

```
\lstdefinestyle{Python}{
morekeywords={super}
}
```

instead.

Comment: This is the best answer for just extending one language's keywords. Thank you!

Comment: Agree with @JeffP, best answer because highlights the difference between lstset and lstdefinestyle.

Comment: This adds the `super` keyword to one _style_, perhaps confusingly named the same as the _language_ Python. See @ASarkar's answer for clarity, where they use lowercase for the style to differentiate it from the language.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to Dominique's and Corentin's answer here's my take on this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{python}{language=Python,
    morekeywords={super},
    ... % more settings for python language
}

\lstdefinestyle{c}{language=C,
    ... % settings for C language
}    

...
\begin{lstlisting}[style = python]
... super
\end{lstlisting}

% changing language
\begin{lstlisting}[style = c]
... 
\end{lstlisting}

% back to python
\begin{lstlisting}[style = python]
... super
\end{lstlisting}
```

This will add the keyword `super` to only `Python` language.

Answer (score 4):

While the [summarization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513766/211230) by [ASarkar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182471/asarkar) of most other answers is a nice workaround, I want to show how you can actually extend an existing language, like requested by the asker. Given the fact that the `HTML` language of `listing` does not highlight HTML 5 elements, let's extend that by some keywords:

```tex
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}[]{HTML}{
    morekeywords={audio, video, canvas, embed, source}
}
```

When you add a HTML listing to your document, just use the `HTML5` language tag instead of `HTML`:

```tex
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5]
<video src="" controls></video>
\end{lstlisting}
```