# Add keyword to a lstlisting language

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extend a language with additional keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28229/extend-a-language-with-additional-keywords)

I'm using the package `listings` to write some Scheme code.

I setted:

```
\lstset{language=Lisp}
```

since "Lisp" is the most similar language i have found within the language values.

My problem is that in Lisp the word "define" is not a keyword, so in my listing it is not in bold style.

Can I add a keyword?How?

Comment: You can even define your own code with `listings`. See "3.2 Language definitions" in the package documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question as implying that you want to *add* the word "define" to the list of keywords or if you want to *remove* it from the list. If it's the former you want, you could change the instruction `\lstset{language=Lisp}` to `\lstset{language=Lisp, morekeywords={define}}`. If it's the latter, you could use the instruction `\lstset{language=Lisp, deletekeywords={define}}`.