Extending listings package language definition
I am trying to extend the listings package's language definitions. In this example, there are several MATLAB key words that are not highlighted using the current definitions, so I thought I'd add my own.
I thought this would work (in $HOME/texmf/tex/latex/listings/lstlang0.sty):
\lst@definelanguage{Matlab}
{ morekeywords={transpose,ctranspose,},
}

but instead, that blew away all existing keyword definitions rather than appending the new ones.
I know how to do this inside the document (e.g., through \lstset), or through \lstdefinestyle, but I don't know how to do this by using lstlang0.sty (which, based on the documentation, I should be able to do...?)
I could have sworn that something similar to this worked in the past, but that could have been an instance of creating a new dialect (which does work) rather than simply extending the list of keywords for the existing language.
Put another way, what is the "right" way to extend keyword lists, other than creating a new dialect?
EDIT: Someone asked for a minimal example, so here you go.
FILE: lstlang0.sty
\lst@definelanguage{Matlab}
{ morekeywords={ctranspose,transpose,%
  },
}

FILE: example.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab]
>> A = eye(2)
>> transpose(A)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

Without the lstlang0.sty file above, eye is recognized as a keyword (boldface, in this example); with lstlang0.sty as above, transpose is recognized, but eye is not.
UPDATE (edit):
It is possible, inside lstlang0.sty, to add
\lst@definelanguage{bash}[]{sh}%
  {morekeywords={gawk,xargs,},
  }

and have those appended as expected, even though there is already a similar command defining the {bash}[]{sh} dialect in lstlang1.sty. So you evidently can append keywords to dialects but not to the base language?

Could you provide a minimal example of the code you used that you thought should have worked but didn't?

I'm not sure but maybe your local file is redefining the rules for Matlab commands. In my system I found on /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty all commands for Matlab language. If you add (requires root privileges) transpose to it, it works as you expect. So, my suggestion is to make a copy of that file into your local folder and edit it as you wish.

It looks like your (karlh's) approach is equivalent to adding \lstdefinelanguage{Matlab}{morekeywords={ctranspose,transpose}} to your preamble.  A relevant question is then https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224093/107497, where the answer is "no, you can't add keywords to a language."

@Teepeemm I added an example of why I thought this worked (in this case, extending the bash dialect of the sh language; the bash dialect is already defined in the base package, with the same syntax).

@Sigur Of course that will work, I was trying to avoid doing that: if I make a copy in my local TeX tree, then I will miss future updates to the base distribution unless I go through and edit them myself.

From the documentation, it looks like bash and sh are two different languages, not one a dialect of the other.  And it seems that your snippet is defining a new "bash" that is an extension of sh.  For example, alias is in (old) bash but not sh and it loses its keyword status.

@Teepemm Ah, I see now. The difference between morekeywords and keywords is not so much between overwrite vs. append (which is what I had interpreted that to mean) so much as the difference between inherit vs. don't inherit. So new dialect definitions will overwrite old dialect definitions, but they will still inherit the base language's definitions.

@karlh After a deep dive into listings, I found a way to add keywords, which I've posted at the other question.  It's possible to extract the relevant parts into custompackage.sty and everything works.  Something goes wrong when I try to extract the relevant parts into lstlang0.sty.

I've figured out what goes wrong: when \lstlang@#2$#1 isn't defined, listings first loads lstlang0.sty.  When this calls my \addKeyWords, listings hasn't finished loading everything, so the variable isn't defined.  \addKeyWords therefore creates \lstinline[language]!!.  Since \lstlang@#2$#1 isn't defined for the inline portion, the whole process repeats.  I'm not sure how to fix that.
