# Listings Highlight Java Annotations

Tags: listings, java

I am typesetting something that has a lot of Java code listings. Because the Java code has a lot of annotations, and that they are important to the reader, I'd like to have them highlighted, like other keywords such as class, public, etc.

I want the output to be in black and white.

I tried using minted, but the bw output does not highlight the annotations.

How can I arm-twist listings to highlight the annotations?

P.S. Here is the lstset that I am using:

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\tt,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  language=Java,                 % the language of the code
  keywordstyle=\bf,
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  tabsize=2                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
}
```

Comment: you should first search for your answer. use `morekeywords={public, void}` .Take a look at this [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115316/add-keywords-to-an-existing-language-in-listings/115326#115326)

Comment: What vvelieve said is partially true. The point is public and void are not annotations; `@Override` is an annotation. What you should do is to add `@Override` as a key world (with the `@`). If you are using classical java annotations this is feasible solution. However if you have many user-defined annotations a better solution is to tell listings to declare every word that comes after `@` as a key word. This is *maybe* achievable by using `moredelim` option. You can have an idea how to do so by reading listings documentation.

Comment: I am looking at moredelim, but it looks like I need to know both the starting and ending characters. Annotations are not required to be ended with anything specific, which I guess would be a mine field for the listings package.

Answer (score 23):

First, some thoughts on `minted`: this great package relies on [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) and AFAIK most of the available styles *does* support Java annotations. Sadly, as you pointed out, the `bw` style doesn't highlight annotations.

One possibility is to create an extended version of this style (in order words, create a new style with `bw` as base) and then include the instruction that sets the formatting for annotations (I just took a quick look at some styles, but failed to determine which instruction is used by Pygments to refer to an annotation).

If you want to try `listings` instead, I'd go with Pouya's suggestion on using custom delimiters. The reason is that, in my humble opinion, since annotations are syntactic metadata, they cannot be treated as keywords or comments, hence a different style to represent them would be a wiser choice.

I know you are using a black and white theme, but I decided to create a colored output just for us to see which style is being applied to each identifier. The concept would be the same, just replace `color` occurrences by the font series you want.

In my code, I'd create two delimiters:

```
moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$},
moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
```

The first, `$$`, is applied to the whole line and it can be used for annotations that are in lines of their own (think of a single line comment here). The second one, `%% ... %%`, behaves like a multiline comment, which encloses everything that is inside these delimiters, and it's useful for annotations that are applied inline to methods or fields.

A sample code is as follows (the Java example here is a courtesy of [Project Lombok](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Java,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  commentstyle=\color{pgreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{pblue},
  stringstyle=\color{pred},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$},
  moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
/**
 * This is a doc comment.
 */
package com.ociweb.jnb.lombok;

import java.util.Date;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NonNull;

$$@Data
$$@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"address","city","state","zip"})
public class Person {
    enum Gender { Male, Female }

    // another comment

    %%@NonNull%% private String firstName;
    %%@NonNull%% private String lastName;
    %%@NonNull%% private final Gender gender;
    %%@NonNull%% private final Date dateOfBirth;

    private String ssn;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: After the line moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$}, the whole code is green in TexStudio. Shouldn't you put moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\$\$}, ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by getting listings to treat annotations like it does comments. Add this to your `lstset`:

```
morecomment=[s][\color{gray}]{@}{\ }
```

In brief: s-type comments have two delimiters, cannot be nested, and are defined as: `morecomment=[s][(optional) <style>]{<startDelimiter>}{<endDelimiter>}`

So the annotations style given above treats any string starting with `@` and ending with a space as a comment, which is typeset in gray.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option `keywordsprefix` as defined [in the docs on page 44](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), e.g.

```
keywordsprefix={@},
```

to highlight all Java annotations (all words starting with `@`). There are currently a few caveats/bugs though:

```
keywordsprefix=<prefix>

All identifers starting with the prefix will be printed as first order
keywords.

Bugs: Currently there are several limitations. (1) The prefix is always
case sensitive. (2) Only one prefix can be defined at a time. (3) If used 
‘standalone’ outside a language definition, the key might work only after 
selecting a nonempty language (and switching back to the empty language 
if necessary). (4) The key does not respect the value of classoffset and
has no optional class number argument.
```