# Extend keyword list for fancyvrb / listings, based on a given language

Tags: listings, verbatim, fancyvrb

I use `fancyvrb` and `listings` packages, and I have defined a language `scala`, which is the default to use.

In one occasion, I have an extension of that language, `escala`, which adds additional keywords. Can I add these keywords for one block of `\begin{Verbatim} ... \end{Verbatim}`, so that they are also highlighted like other keywords (in my case boldface)? Or can I easily define a new language based on `scala`, merely adding the new keywords without a full copy of the scala definition?

It appears that [this is a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28229/extend-a-language-with-additional-keywords), however it destructively adds keywords to a language (e.g. `python`), whereas I want to preserve `scala` and instead have a second language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\lstset` in the `formatcom` sectino of a particular `Verbatim` block works. Keywords added with `morekeywords` do add to the existing keywords:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[formatcom={\lstset{morekeywords={event,before,after,imperative}}}]
  ...
\end{Verbatim}
```