# How to suggest updates to lstlisting Java keywords?

Tags: lstlisting, java

It seems the `listings` package does not provide syntax highlighting for the following words in Java:

```
strictfp
assert
enum
var
```

Is there any way to add them manually or somewhere to file a bug report to get them added?

Comment: Check this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28230/120578... Hope it helps to define any keyword with any highlighting.

Comment: AFAIK the standard language definitions are all maintained by the `listings` maintainer. So if you think something is missing, you should probably direct the feature request to him. His e-mail address can be found on the very first page of the [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).