# Highlight new C++ keywords introduced in C++11, C++17, and C++20 in the listings package

Tags: listings, keywords

C++11 added a bunch of new keywords: `alignas`, `alignof`, `constexpr`, etc. But they don't seem to be supported by the `listings` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language = [11]C++,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{blue},
  columns = flexible
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  constexpr int i = 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The `constexpr` is not recognized as a keyword:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

How can I enable the C++11 keywords?
How about C++20 keywords like `requires`, `concept`, `consteval`, etc.?

(**Note**: This is a self-answer question.
I know this question can be closed as a duplicate of many others,
such as [*Extend a language with additional keywords?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28229),
but they do not specifically address new C++ keywords.
I am frequently asked about this,
and I also need this very often,
so I decided to write it down for future reference.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)

## C++11 keywords

The `listings` package has built in support for C++11. Use `language = [11]C++` option to alignas (no pun intended) C++11:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language = [11]C++,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{blue},
  columns = flexible
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  constexpr int i = 0;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This yields the desired result:

[image]

## C++11 *identifiers with special meaning*

### Treated as keywords

C++11 introduces two *identifiers with special meaning*: `override` and `final`. By default, they are not highlighted.
You can add them manually to the keyword list:

```
\lstset{
  morekeywords = {final, override}
}
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language = [11]C++,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{blue},
  columns = flexible
}

\lstset{
  morekeywords = {final, override}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  override
  final
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

### Treated specially

If you want differentiate between keywords and identifiers with special meaning,
you can override (no pun intended) this by introducing a special emphasis class for them:

```
\lstset{
  emph = {[11]final, override},
  emphstyle = \color{green}
}
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language = [11]C++,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{blue},
  columns = flexible
}

\lstset{
  emph = {[11]final, override},
  emphstyle = \color{green}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  constexpr
  override
  final
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This yields the final (no pun intended) result:

[image]

## Other

For future reference, here I give the list of C++20 keywords, C++20 identifiers with special meaning, etc. If the maintainer of the `listings` package sees this, please add the relevant part to `language = [20]C++`!

### C++20 keywords

```
\lstset{
  morekeywords = {
    char8_t,
    concept,
    co_await,
    co_return,
    co_yield,
    requires
  }
}
```

### C++20 identifiers with special meaning

```
\lstset{
  emph = {[20]
    import,
    module
  }
}
```

(Note: the original version included `audit` and `axiom`.  The Contract TS was later removed from C++20, so `audit` and `axiom` are no longer identifiers with special meaning in C++20.)

### Transactional Memory Technical Specification (TM TS) keywords

```
\lstset{
  morekeywords = {
    atomic_cancel,
    atomic_commit,
    atomic_noexcept,
    synchronized
  }
}
```

### Transactional Memory Technical Specification (TM TS) identifiers with special meaning

```
\lstset{
  emph = {[42]
    transaction_safe,
    transaction_dynamic
  }
}
```

### Reflection TS

```
\lstset{
  morekeywords = {
    reflexpr
  }
}
```

---

(Note: all numbers were chosen arbitrarily. Don't forget to adjust them to avoid name clash with existing identifier classes!)

Comment: This can also be provided as an optional clause with each listing. Note the curly brackets: `\begin{lstlisting}[language={[11]C++}]`.